# Fulltext search using Sequelize (Postgres)

Tags: node.js, postgresql, sequelize.js, full-text-search

So I've been working with `sequelize` for a while now, and after juggling with `elasticsearch`, I decided to make use of `postgres's` support for `fts`.

It looks like just at the start of this year `sequelize` added support for `TSVector` which is necessary for `FTS` implementation. Although I just can't find any documentation whatsover anywhere.

[The pull request](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/pull/12955)

All help is appreciated!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look at changes for the PR you will see new operator `Op.match` and the new data type `DateTypes.TSVECTOR`.
You can now define a field like this in a model:

```js
...
textField: {
   type: DataTypes.TSVECTOR
}
...
```

And you simply can use it like this in `where` option:

```
textField: {
  [Op.match]: Sequelize.fn('to_tsquery', 'fat & rat') // match text search for strings 'fat' and 'rat' (PG only)
}
```

See [this readme](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize/blob/90885c3f0d7f0d3c72f1c5df8a64b27735f224dd/docs/manual/core-concepts/model-querying-basics.md)